# Picture in Picture for quicktime?

Tags: macos, quicktime

I can't seem to find Picture-in-Picture (PiP) in QuickTime 10.4.

Is macOS Sierra's new PiP feature only for Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuickTime Player in macOS Catalina has a Picture in Picture button.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

QuickTime has had this feature for a while now, well before Sierra.

1. Open a video with QuickTime Player.
2. View > Float on Top.
3. Right-click or Control-click on the QuickTime Player icon in the Dock.
4. Options > Assign To: All Desktops. (This is available for any app.)

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Also, to answer your explicit question, PIP is specifically a feature of Safari and iTunes.

Comment: Just for the record, this is not the same feature. PIP floats above desktops so when switching spaces it is still in the corner of the screen, whereas in quicktime the floating window is still fixed to a space.

Comment: To add to the previous comment by @GeorgeGreen: you can work around this limitation by right-clicking QuickTime’s Dock icon, clicking options, and assigning it to "all desktops".

Comment: While it is not the same feature, it definitely fulfills a similar end-result that many users may be looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately does not allow floating windows above screens set to full-screen mode.

Comment: This workaround does not fulfill the functionality provided by PiP.

Answer (score 13):

A good solution is to simply drag a video file to the address bar in Safari and use its PIP feature.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Great little hack! Only shame is that while in PIP mode, the seek controls are missing, so if you need to skip forward or back, you need to come out of PIP, move the playback head, then put it back in PIP mode.

Comment: Good thinking! Never occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me using Quicktime 10.5:

1. Start QuickTime
2. Right click the "QuickTime" icon in the dock, select "New Movie Recording"
3. Select the new movie window, drag it to where you want, resize
4. Select "View/Float on top" so now your movie window displaying the web cam is locked to the top view
5. Right click the "QuickTime" icon in the dock, select "New Screen Recording"
6. Double click the webcam movie window to clear the record bar (so it looks clean)
7. Start recording now, when done press "cmd + ctrl + escape" to stop recording.

This is working 100% :)